# How to collapse Bootstrap table row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar's years view, got it from [here](https://github.com/tpruvot/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v2.2.7-yearview) . I want to display the years as Blocks (vertically) - when the site is viewed in mobile...

Is it possible to change bootstrap table's display, from horizontal to vertical?
Or maybe the best way is to create a condition to set yearColumns to 1 when ever the view is change?

Here is my JS :

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            firstDay: 1,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'

            },
            defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
            defaultView: 'month',
            yearColumns: 3,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, 
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true, 
   );}
```

Here is the [current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT1OY.png)

Comment: Got it - used Jquery.

Comment: Can you add your answer, so that it avoids spam answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var current_page_size = $(this).width();
        if (current_page_size >= 800) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                yearColumns: 3,
                });
               } else {
               yearColumns: 1,
               }
```